# From a group of 8 women and 6 men a committee consisting of 3 men and 3 women is to be formed. How many different committees are possible if…

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In the book A First Course in probability (8th edition) there is a problem at the end on the paragraph about combinatorics which states:

> From a group of 8 women and 6 men a committee consisting of 3 men and 3 women is to be formed. How many different committees are possible if:
> a) 2 of the men refuse to serve together?

I guessed I could find all the possible committee of 3 men and 3 women, then subtract the number of committees which contains the 2 men. Thus:

$${8 \choose 3}{6 \choose 3} - 4{8 \choose 3} = 896 $$

Which is correct, according to the solutions provided at the end of the book.

But later I thought, isn't $896$ the number of committees of ordered couples of a group of $3$ men and a group of $3$ women? Isn't, say:

{Jim, Jay, John} {Martha, Annah, Stacy}

different from

{Martha, Annah, Stacy} {Jim, Jay John}, by this formula?

Am I "ordering" the $2$ groups by not dividing by $2$ each of them?

Comment: Your formula is correct. It does not envisage the sixtuple (Martha, Annah, Stacy, Jim, Jay John) at all, but only counts sixtuples beginning with three men.

Comment: You are ordering the two groups, but not because of failing to divide by $2$. The mere fact that you are multiplying together the numbers of ways of forming the groups means you are implicitly ordering them. This is not a bad thing; it's exactly what you want: the set of ordered pairs $(W,M)$, where $W$ is a set of women and $M$ is a set of men, is in one-to-one correspondence with the set of committees $W\cup M$ and is what your formula $\binom{8}{3}\binom{6}{3}$ counts.

Comment: And if you were to cook up an alternative counting procedure that did somehow manage to count both types of pair, $(W,M)$ and $(M,W)$, you'd have a two-to-one correspondence between pairs and committees. That would be a problem that would need to be corrected by dividing by $2$.

Answer (score 0):

In this question nothing mentioned about their order of picking. So we don't need to think about that.

In case you need to arrange them in order. You can multiply with 6!